# How to disable mouse left click?

Tags: javascript, jsf, cursor

I want to disable mouse left click. I use the following script but not work.

```
<h:form>
        <a4j:commandButton value="TestButton" onclick="alert('button cliked')"/>
</h:form>
```

JavaScript is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN | Event.MOUSEUP | Event.CLICK);
        document.onmousedown = clickIE4;
        document.onmouseup = clickIE4;
        document.onclick = clickIE4;

        function clickIE4()
        {
            return false; 
        }
</script>
```

Help me.
Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Isn't `onclick="alert("button cliked")"` a syntax error? Also, out of curiosity, what's your use case?

Answer (score 6):

You are going about this incorrectly. You want to disable the button (enabled=false), not capture mouse clicks.

Answer (score 3):

When using that style of handler, return `false` from the handler code:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="TestButton" onclick="alert('button clicked'); return false;"/>
```

As [theatrus said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130310/how-to-disable-mouse-left-click/3130329#3130329), though, if your goal is to disable the button, you're better off actually disabling the button rather than preventing clicks on it. But in terms of your question "how do I disable a left click," that's the answer.

More thoroughly, there are two different ways to attach event handlers:

DOM0 (the style you've used): Return `false` from the handler code to stop the event (prevent it bubbling up to other elements) and prevent the default action:

```
<someElement onclick="return false;">
```

DOM2 (with JavaScript code): DOM2 handlers are attached via `addEventListener` (or `attachEvent`, on IE). Here's an example, assuming an element with the `id` "foo":

```
// Attaching:
var elm = document.getElementById("foo");
if (elm.attachEvent) {
    elm.attachEvent("onclick", handler);
}
else if (elm.addEventListener) {
    elm.addEventListener("click", handler, false);
}

// Handler:
function handler(event) {
    // DOM standard is that `event` is an argument to the
    // handler; IE uses a global event object instead.
    // This line handles that.
    event = event || window.event;

    // Cancelling bubbling:
    if (event.stopPropagation) {
        // DOM standard
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
    else {
        // Older mechanism
        event.cancelBubble = true;
    }

    // Preventing default action:
    if (event.preventDefault) {
        // DOM standard
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        // Older mechanism
        event.returnValue = false;
    }
}
```

Some reference material:

- [The DOM2 standard Event interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event)
- [MSDN Event object docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535863(VS.85).aspx) (for IE stuff)